# How to permit a parameter of this syntax : model[name[var]]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security, post

I have a form generated by this code :

```
<%= form_with(model: category, local: true) do |form| %>

  <%= form.text_field :slug %>

 <% @translations.each do |translation| %>
    <%= form.text_field 'name[' + translation.language.code + ']' %>
 <% end %>

  <%= form.submit %>

<% end %>
```

The input name is `category[name[en]]` (as I want) but how to allow the parameter who's name is `category[name[en]]` (the `en` change)

Currently I have this :

```
def location_params
       params.require(:category).permit(:slug, :name)
end
```

And I get `Unpermitted parameter: :name` When I do `p location_params`

This is what is transmitted :

```
_method patch
authenticity_token  atoken
category[name[en]]  avalue
category[name[fr]]  anothervalue
category[slug]  meeting
commit  Update+Category
utf8    ✓
```

Comment: have you tried `permit(:slug, name: [:en])` because that appears to be what you are actually sending. How is `en` changing when you are hard coding the string?

Comment: What does `name` correspond to? Is it a nested model? Is it a serialized hash attribute? How are you expecting it to persist in your db?

Comment: Can you show the HTML output created by that file and also the web console for when you submit so we can see exactly how the params are coming across to the controller? Are you trying to pass the controller a named hash with a key (i.e  name[:en])? This question needs a lot more code and example of expected results/output.

Comment: is `name[]` a finite list? If it is you could just do `.permit(:slug, name: [:en, :de, :fr])` where `[:en, :de, :fr]` are all your anticipated values. `permit` just says allow these things so if they don't exists there is really no issue

Comment: @engineersmnky I have edited my post, it's not hardcoded, it's a variable

Comment: @kiddorails name is an attribute from another model

Comment: then hows this `params.require(:category).permit(:slug, name: Language.all.map { |lang| lang.code.intern})`.

Comment: @NinoTreyssat-Vincent if it's an attribute of different model, what are you trying to do is basically submit a nested form. You should read about it here - https://rubyplus.com/articles/3681-Complex-Forms-in-Rails-5

Comment: @Beartech I'm not sure what you mean by web console, I've added some more context, and would be happy to add more

Comment: @engineersmnky It's allowed ! And without surprises it raise `unknown attribute 'name' for Category.`  I should read what @kiddorails linked.

Comment: @NinoTreyssat-Vincent yeah that is a completely different error that has to do with how you are actually creating the Category object.

Comment: The web console is the terminal window where your rails server is running, the place where you typed 'rails s' to start the web server so you could test your app in your browser. If you look at that window it gives you tons of info as it shows the server receiving and sending information. It's output will show you the exact structure of the parameters hah that is being received.